# Ruby on rails nginx gives directory of is forbidden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, passenger, rbenv

I have an nginx server with passenger that I am trying to run a ruby on rails app. I am using rbenv and am deploying using capistrano.

I keep getting an error message that is as follows:

```
directory index of "[/srv/[directory]]" is forbidden, client: [my client ip], server: [my domain], request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "[my domain]"
```

My nginx config for the site:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name [my domain];
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env    production;
    root         /srv/[my app name]/current/public;
passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
        passenger_enabled on;
    }
    location / { 
            passenger_enabled on;
    }
```

}

And my config for passenger in my nginx.conf file is as follows:

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;

passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
```

Comment: Run CHMOD 700 on your directory.

Comment: I have tried that. I have even tried with 777. It did not help.

Comment: Try doing it again with the "-R" option (to recursively chmod all the contents)

Comment: I have done that. Sorry for not posting the info about the directory

Comment: Try removing excess `passenger_enabled`, since you already have it in `server`